# Maximum length of an image file for a j2me application?

Tags: java-me, filesystems, long-filenames

I am building a application in j2me where i will receive an image via a Wireless connection. I want to know what can be the maximum length of the filename when i save it. My main motive is to store some information about the image via its filename.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of data that you want to store in RMS can be set in JAD file using MIDlet-Data-Size attribute. If the phone is JTWI profile complaint, the application can store 30 K data in RMS.

If this attribute is set, the AMS will check for the availability of space requested by application before downloading it. This way you can be safe that if the phone downloads the application, it would run successfully.

May be you can find some useful information in this discussion:
http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?125151-Min-size-of-RMS-on-MIDP-2.0-Devices